# Unable to register spring config client with eureka server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I have a eureka server up and running fine and am trying to register my config client application with eureka server, but unable to register the instance with eureka server

**Config Client Configuration in application.yml**

`eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/`

**Eureka server configuration - application.yml**

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:8761}

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

Eureka server configuration - bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${CONFIG_SERVER_URL:http://localhost:9898}
```

Comment: Did you added the @EnableDiscoveryClient anotation in the client?

Comment: i have added @EnableEurekaClient  annotation but i have tried with EnableDiscoveryClient also .. same issue

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors..up and working fine

Comment: Why for the same Eureka server configuration, in two different files, you have defined two different port values? First is _8761_, and second is _9898_.

Comment: 9898 is my cloud config server port..i just added and tried..but without that also its not  working..all other service which is not consuming config server(without config client dependency) is getting registered

Comment: Did you try to put defaultZone value too in the Eureka application.yml ?
eureka.client.serviceurl.defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

Comment: yeah in my eureka client application i mentioned as defaultZone. same problem continues @ctorrez04

Comment: Actually my app is protected with basic auth. is there any configuration changes needed?? to register as eureka client

Comment: can you share both pom.xml? and are you sure that client app is not showing any errors in the console? because if it's doing well it should show that it cannot connect to eureka or something